# rails assigning existing id on creation

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-5

I have a workers table. This table has only one field that is name. In the rails console when I try

```
w=Worker.new(name: "Dumping")
w.save
```

The above code returns error

```
ActiveRecord::RecordNotUnique (PG::UniqueViolation: ERROR:  duplicate key value violates unique constraint "workers_pkey"
DETAIL:  Key (id)=(6) already exists.
: INSERT INTO "workers" ("name", "created_at", "updated_at") VALUES ($1, $2, $3) RETURNING "id")
```

Rails is assigning the id to record which already exists. Please help me resolve this issue.

Comment: Can you show your Worker model, and the table definition in your schema?

Comment: This is possible if someone inserted a record into this table some time ago providing an explicit id - in this case Postgress will not call `next_val` and thus the sequence that generates ids will not be "updated" and you can get conflicts like this. To fix the issue without messing with the existing records you could, for example, update the sequence manually, via smth like `select setval(<your sequence>, (select max(id) from workers))`

Comment: My bet is that you probably tested it a while ago and provided explicit id, have a look at your DB table, you will probably find that record.